# Call statements

Tags: vb.net, logic, call, statements

I am trying to use call statements in Visual Studio and having some issues understanding the logic. I am trying to create a windows form program to calculate "Net Pay" in a payroll situation. Just looking for some insight on how these statements work...

I am mostly just confused on how to calculate the Overtime pay portion and if there is no Overtime, then just Regular pay...

This is what I have so far:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hours As Double
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim regpay As Double
    Dim overpay As Double

    hours = TextBox5.Text
    rate = TextBox4.Text

    If hours > 40 Then
        Regular(regpay)
        Overtime(overpay)
    Else
        Regular(regpay)
    End If

End Sub

Sub Regular(ByRef regpay As Double)

End Sub

Sub Overtime()

End Sub
```

I'm sure it's simple, I'm just having a hard time understanding the logic and syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend defining Regular and Overtime as functions that return the computed values, i.e:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hours As Double
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim regpay As Double
    Dim overpay As Double

    hours = TextBox5.Text
    rate = TextBox4.Text

    If hours > 40 Then
        regpay = Regular(40, rate)
        overpay = Overtime(hours - 40, rate)
    Else
        regpay = Regular(hours, rate)
    End If

    Dim netPay = regPay + overPay
    ' TODO: write netPay back to the form
End Sub

Function Regular(hours As Double, rate As Double) As Double
    Return hours * rate
End Function

Function Overtime(hours As Double, rate As Double) As Double
    Return hours * rate ' Note overtime may be paid at a different rate
End Function
```

Also for accuracy in financial calculations I'd recommend using the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) type over double.

Comment: If hours > 40 Then
        regpay = Regular(40, rate)
        overpay = Overtime(hours - 40, rate)
    Else
        regpay = Regular(hours, rate)
    End If

Throws syntax error that "Regular(hours, rate)" returns no value...

Comment: Also, afterwards, I need to be able to display what the gross pay is, what the net pay is and so on...I'm supposed to have a call statement for each one of those and I'm confused on how those values can be carried down from each call statement before...

Comment: @tbeauregard1 sorry, as it's a code fragment I can't type check, have updated hope it works for you now. Values are returned from functions with the return statement, values are passed to functions as arguments. Typically net pay is pay after tax and gross pay is pay before tax, so if tax is not already factored into the rate, you'll need to first compute gross then net pay.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need one method to do this. As a quick point of order before I continue, pretty much any time you're working with money you should use the Decimal type instead of Double:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim hours As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
    Dim rate As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox4.Text)   
    Dim regpay As Decimal 
    Dim overpay As Decimal 

    If hours > 40D Then
        regpay = CalculatePay(40D, rate)
        overpay = CalculatePay(hours - 40D, rate * 1.5D)
    Else
        regpay = CalculatePay(hours, rate)
        overpay = 0D
    End If

End Sub

Function CalculatePay(ByVal hours As Decimal, ByVal rate As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return hours * rate
End Function
```